# Disable text-field blue highlight in Chrome Extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, textfield, highlight

I'm working on a Chrome extension that let's you edit a small text field, and I'm finding the blue highlight around the text field when clicked really annoying.

Is there a way (preferably using CSS) to make this highlight slightly thinner? I find it's a bit too thick, and needs slimming. Thanks!

Screenshot of blue highlight:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Yes; just assign 'none' to the 'outline' property:

```
input {
    outline: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/62kh7/).

Please consider that the outline is a UI feature to highlight the currently-active/-focused form element and removing that visual cue might hinder some users.

---

**Edited** in response to the comment lefty by Beakr, the OP, in comments below:

> I was intending to disable it/modify it to see what it could do.

To adjust the style for the `outline` you can access the individual properties:

```
elementSelector:focus {
    outline-width: 4px; /* thin, medium, thick or standard CSS length units */
    outline-style: auto; /* or 'inherit', 'none' or border-style (solid, dashed, dotted...) */
    outline-color: #f90; /* standard CSS colors */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/62kh7/1/).

The above can also be condensed, using shorthand notation:

```
elementSelector:focus {
    outline: 4px auto #f90;
}
```

The smallest of the possible outline measurements that can be used are either:

```
elementSelector:focus {
    outline-width: thin; /* or 1px */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though I do agree, I was intending to disable it/modify it to see what it could do.

Comment: So...would you care to update your question to ask what it is that you want to *do* with the outline?

Comment: Its acceptable to remove this if you replace it with something similar, for instance I have implemented my own focus styles like so:
.formTextInput{
  padding: 7px 0px 7px 9px;
  border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px dimgray;
  border: 1px solid dimgrey;
  outline: none;
  margin:5px;
}
.formTextInput:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px orange;
}