# Dropdown menu's in css, but when clicked they sometimes highlight blue and aren't triggered unless clicked again and I can't figure out why

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

It works perfectly for the content of the drop down menu, here is the code:

```
.mainButton {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  color: #65D7EF;
}

.mainButton a {
  color: #65D7EF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .mainButton {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #65D7EF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0F0F0F;
  border-top: 2px solid #0F0F0F;
  font-size: .75em;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #28292A;
}
```

but if I were to cut it all down to this (I have these 3 buttons and 2 that are dropdown buttons with content, but I'll leave the dropdowns out as they aren't the problem):

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn a { color: white; }

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and code a few pages with this:

```
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "pc.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="News.html">News</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="About.html">About</a></button>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
<head>
  <title>About</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "pc.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="News.html">News</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="About.html">About</a></button>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

<head>
  <title>News</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "pc.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="News.html">News</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="About.html">About</a></button>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

And click between the 3 buttons on the page, it will eventually give a blue border to one of the buttons and not trigger. I'll have to click it once more in order for it to trigger and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: show us some working code

Comment: It is for starters not a good idea to wrap an `a` element inside a `button` element. The blue highlight you are talking about is probably the `outline` color google chrome applies by default to elements that are `focused`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455067/disable-text-field-blue-highlight-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Alright, thank you! I am very new to html (as you can probably tell). I figured out how to remove the blue outline, but that still leaves the issue of not being able to click once to activate the button. Click once and it highlights, click again and it activates. Yet it doesn't do this EVERY time which confuses me even more. If an a element should not be wrapped by a button element, what do you propose I should use?